# Wrapping c++ class for python (with opencv), gives "undefined symbol"

Tags: python, c++, opencv, wrapper

Background:
I am trying to wrap a c++ class, so that I can use it from python. But as soon as I use anything from opencv (like: "cv::Mat frame;" I get an "undefined symbol" error. As soon as I remove the line "cv::VideoCapture wcam;" everything compiles and executes as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

webcam.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


class webcam{
    private:
        cv::VideoCapture wcam;
    public:
        webcam();
        void nextFrame();
        //cv::Mat getNewFrame();
};


webcam::webcam(){}
void webcam::nextFrame(){
    std::cout << "TESTING TESTING";
}


extern "C" {
    webcam* webcam_new(){ return new webcam(); }
    void test(webcam* wc) {wc->nextFrame();}
    //void Foo_bar(Foo* camCon){ foo->bar(); }
}
```

compiling:

```
g++ -c -fPIC webcam.cpp -o webcam.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,webcam.so -o webcam.so  webcam.o
```

cam.py:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./webcam.so')

class camCon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.webcam_new()
     def test(self):
        lib.test(self.obj)

fooo = camCon()
fooo.test()
```

Error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapp.py", line 5, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./webcam.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./webcam.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv12VideoCaptureC1Ev
```

(I am aware that it is possible to use openCV in python directly)

**UPDATE**

I found that using 
"cv::Mat frame"
is OK. but
"cv::VideoCapture webcam"
is not.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to copy OpenCV dll (and lib?) files to a directory with your `webcam.so` library - for me ot looks like Python can't find some symbol during loading you lib.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. I copied all libopencv.so files from /usr/local/lib and also all .h/.hpp files from usr/local/include/opencv /usr/local/include/opencv2.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's stupid and I'd like to add a comment but my rep is bad....

Anyhow, did you try just removing the `cv::` part since you're already using the `using namespace cv` directive?

Also I'm not sure how `cv` and `cv2` like each other? I'm not quite sure they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

When compiling for a shared lib I had to add the libraries  like this:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,webcam.so -o webcam.so  webcam.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
```